# $(-T,T) \subset \mathbb{R}$ open and $U \subset (-T,T)$ an open subset. Then $(-T,T)\setminus U$ can be assumed as compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(-T,T) \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval and $U \subset (-T,T)$ an open subset. Then $(-T,T)\setminus U$ can be assumed as compact.

How do I see that?

**EDIT:**

This is actually part of a proof of the regularity of the Lebesgue measure.

The statement to be proved is the following:

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue-measurable, then $\lambda(E)=\text{sup}_{K\subset E, K \;\text{compact}}\; \lambda(K)$

The first step is to show this for an interval $(-T,T),\; T>0$ containing $E$, and then in step 2 one expands the interval.

We have $\lambda(E) = 2T - \lambda((-T,T)\setminus E)$ by the additivity of the measure $\lambda$. It follows with the outer regularity property of $\lambda$ that

$\lambda(E) = 2T - \text{inf}_{U\supset (-T,T)\setminus E,\;U\; \text{open}} \lambda(U)$

Since $U$ and $(-T,T)$ are open, w.l.o.g it suffices to take the infimum over open sets $U$ that are already contained in $(-T,T)$, which gives

$\lambda(E) = 2T - \text{inf}_{U\supset (-T,T)\setminus E,\;U\; \text{open},\; U\subset(-T,T)} \lambda(U)$

For such an open $U\subset (-T,T)\;$ the set $(-T,T)\setminus U$ is compact, at least after having made T bigger.

**If one considered $[-T,T]\setminus U$, this would be true, but then I don't see why he didn't start with $[-T,T]$ in the first place.**

Comment: You can't. $(-2,2)\setminus (-1,1)$ is not compact as $\bigcup U_n$ with $U_n=(-2,2-\frac1n)$ has no finite subcover.

Comment: What do you mean by "can be assumed as"?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: by "can be assumed as compact" I mean that it can be regarded as compact after, for example, making T bigger.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Hmm, OK, I'll make an edit an post the whole proof up until the point where this is mentioned - obviously I'm missing something here.